# Setting the width and height of a bootstrap modal with a youtube video

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have the following code

```
<div id="MainV3_VideoModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe id="MainV3_Video" class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/test" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to set the width and height of the modal with the youtube video so that it takes 85% of the width of the screen and that the height fits the aspect ratio of 16/9. How can I do this? I tried using css and setting the max-width on the modal-dialog but that's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following css. This will maintain the 16x9 ratio however you will also need to add some styling to keep the modal centered.

```
.modal-content{
height: calc((85vw/16)*9);
width: 85vw;
}
```

Comment: How do I make the modal centered?

Comment: You can add the following CSS to the modal-content. (You may have to adjust the values a bit. ) Good luck!


    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;

Comment: how do we center it vertically?